# Properties of Lie brackets

Tags: lie-algebras

I'm doing some proofs connected with Lie algebra. And now for the second time I get something like this: let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra. Then $[0, y] = [y, 0] =0$ $\forall y \in \mathfrak{g}$. I wonder why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Lie bracket is bilinear. In particular, $[\alpha x,y]=\alpha [x,y]=[x,\alpha y]$ for all $\alpha\in K$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So $[0, y] = [0\cdot0, y] = [0, 0\cdot y]$?
Do we also have $[AB, C] = A[B, C] + [A, C]B; A,B,C \in \mathfrak{g}$? If yes, why?

Comment: Yes, this is true for the case that $[A,B]=AB-BA$ for endomorphisms.